# Java DOM Parser - Parse nested XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I have a problem with reading nested XML and I really need some help.

This is an example of input xml:

```
<Node>Calls
<Node>Calls1
    <Node id="1">Service
        <Node>RenewAccount
            <Tariff>SetField
                <PreDefinedField>New value
                    <Index>
                        <Value datatype="Integer">100</Value>
                    </Index>
                </PreDefinedField>
                <CopyFrom/>
                <Value/>
            </Tariff>
            <Tariff>SetField
                <PreDefinedField>New value
                    <Index>
                        <Value datatype="Integer">200</Value>
                    </Index>
                </PreDefinedField>
                <CopyFrom/>
                <Value>4800</Value>
            </Tariff>
        </Node>
    </Node>
</Node>
<Node>Calls2
    <Node id="2">Service
        <Node>RenewAccount
            <Tariff>SetField
                <PreDefinedField>New value
                    <Index>
                        <Value datatype="Integer">300</Value>
                    </Index>
                </PreDefinedField>
                <CopyFrom/>
                <Value/>
            </Tariff>
            <Tariff>SetField
                <PreDefinedField>New value
                    <Index>
                        <Value datatype="Integer">400</Value>
                    </Index>
                </PreDefinedField>
                <CopyFrom/>
                <Value>36000</Value>
            </Tariff>
        </Node>
    </Node>
</Node>
```

What should I do in order to loop through this structure and replace two Integer values between two child nodes?

The main thing that is bothering me is that I can't check in which child Node I am. How exactly to retrive values "FirstChild" and "SecondChild"?
I tried already but constantly I'm reading everything under Node element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this really your input file? It looks somewhat ... special. Mixed content (text and sub elements) and multiple elements with the same id. Don't think it's  valid.

Comment: It really is. I know it is looks special, but it is.
You can observe only first two rows and tell me how to take only "FirstChild" and that is it. That would be helpful also

Comment: Please add the code statement in the posts .even xml' contents are mismatch with improper tags

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid XML file, have you tried any XML validators?

Comment: Ok, I added new example of XML file, this one is valid. Point is the same, how I can read this file properly? For example, if I need to read only Calls1, nothing else, what should I do?

Comment: your question is vague, which values are you trying to retrieve from this xml file?